# Issue not getting a result when stuff is used

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the `stuff` function to create an comma separated value

`stuff` works if I run it alone, but when I use in combination with another column to check against, it is failing.

Is it due to datatype issue?

Here is my code

```
and cast(verifyemails as varchar(max)) in (select STUFF((SELECT Distinct  ',' + '''' + cast(emails as varchar(max)) + ''''  from roleslist
left join users on users.fkuserid = roleslist.fkroleuserid  
where 
and fkUserID = 350 
group by emails 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')
```

The above does not give the results, even the emails do exists in the table, but the below query is working if I run it alone. Does it have to anything with `trim` or anything?

```
select STUFF((SELECT Distinct  ',' + '''' + cast(emails as varchar(max)) + ''''  from roleslist
left join users on users.fkuserid = roleslist.fkroleuserid  
where 
and fkUserID = 350 
group by emails 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')
```

Comment: can you format your answer, bit hard to understand what you are suggesting

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer so you can get the formatting and provide a little more detail.

Comment: `where and fkUserID = 350` is not correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing an `IN` you shouldn't bother creating a comma-delimited string. If you use a comma-delimited string you need to use `LIKE` instead of `IN`. Should be something like this...

```
and 
(select STUFF((SELECT Distinct  ',' + '''' + cast(emails as varchar(max)) + ''''  
 from roleslist
 left join users
     on users.fkuserid = roleslist.fkroleuserid  
 where fkUserID = 350 
 group by emails 
 FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'') LIKE '%' + cast(verifyemails as varchar(max)) + '%'
```

Or you could simply remove the comma-delimiting stuff and do this...

```
and cast(verifyemails as varchar(max)) in 
(select cast(emails as varchar(max)) from roleslist
 left join users
     on users.fkuserid = roleslist.fkroleuserid  
 where fkUserID = 350 
 group by emails)
```